# How to find limit of this sequence $a_{n+1} = \frac{2a_{n}^2}{a_{n}^2+1}$ and prove it

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$\forall \alpha \in \Bbb R$ let define a sequence by $$a_{0}=\alpha , a_{n+1} = \frac{2a_{n}^2}{a_{n}^2+1}$$  prove that for all $\alpha$ there exsists $: \lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}$ and calculate it

I tried to say that if $\alpha>1$ or $<1 $ then the limit is $1$ and if  $|\alpha|<1$ then the limit is $0$
but I don't know if this is true and if it is how do I prove it?

Comment: Here's a notable fact: the sequence is defined by $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$, where $f(x) = \frac{2x^2}{x^2 + 1}$.  Because this function is continuous, the limit $L$ must satisfy $f(L) = L$.

Comment: Once you prove that the limit exists then determining what it is is easy, just take the limit of both sides. This will give you $a_\infty = \frac{2a_\infty^2}{a_\infty^2+1}$ which is equivalent to a cubic equation that factors well.

Comment: The sequence has positive terms
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{2a_{n}^2}{a_{n}^2+1}\geq0$$
and from $a_n+\dfrac{1}{a_n}\geq2$ then $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** you can use the following:
$$\frac{2a_n^2}{1+a_n^2}= 2-\frac{2}{1+a_n^2}\geq 0$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $\alpha=0$ then $a_n=0,\forall n.$ If $\alpha=1$ then $a_n=1,\forall n.$ So assume $\alpha\ne 0,1.$ Prove that

- $0<a_n<2,\forall n\ge 1.$
- $a_1<a_2<\cdots$ if $|\alpha|> 1$ and $a_1>a_2>\cdots$ if $|\alpha|< 1.$
- So the limit $L$ exists and it satisfies $L=\dfrac{2L^2}{L^2+1}.$

Comment: but from here we get $L_{1}=0$ and $L_{2}=1$ so whch one is the limit?

Comment: @needhelp If $|\alpha|>1$ then the sequence $a_1,a_2,\cdots$ is increasing and since $a_1>0$ the limit is $1.$ If $|\alpha|<1$ the sequence $a_1,a_2,\cdots$ is decreasing and the limit is $0.$

Comment: since we say that the sequence is increasing and $0<a_{n}<2$ so it appears that $a_{n}$ getting closer and closer to $2$ so why the limit when $|α|>1$ isn't $2$?

Answer (score 0):

For any $a_0$ we have $a_1\in[0,2]$. If $|a_0|>1$ we actually have $a_1\in[1,2]$ and $f(x)=\frac{2x^2}{x^2+1}$ is a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) over $[1,2]$, so $a_n$ converges to the only fixed point of $f(x)$ over $[1,2]$, i.e. $1$.
If $|a_0|<1$ then $a_1\in[0,1)$ and $a_1\geq a_2 \geq a_3\geq \ldots \geq 0$. Since $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is weakly decreasing and positive it is convergent, but the only fixed point of $f(x)$ in $[0,1)$ is $0$. Summarizing,
$$ a_n\to 1\quad\text{or}\quad a_n\to 0 $$
according to $|a_0|\geq 1$ or $|a_0|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** If $a_n\gt1$, then $a_n^2\gt a_n$ and
$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}-1
&=\frac{a_n^2-1}{a_n^2+1}\\
&=\frac{a_n+1}{a_n^2+1}\left(a_n-1\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
so that $0\lt a_{n+1}-1\lt a_n-1$.

**Hint 2:** If $0\lt a_n\lt1$, then
$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}
&=a_n\frac{2a_n}{a_n^2+1}\\
&=a_n\left(1-\frac{\left(a_n-1\right)^2}{a_n^2+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$
so that $0\lt a_{n+1}\le a_n$